# Simple server-side html/JS router for three apps

Tags: javascript, html

I'm not a javascript programmer but have a need to do very simple routing in my website's main index.htm file. Situation: We have, let's say, three main ISAPI applications, app1.dll, app2.dll and app3.dll, all hosted by the same in-house server.

These also represent three external domains, e.g., app1.com, app2.com and app3.com, all of which hit the same server and index.htm page. What I want to do in my index.htm page is to simply redirect to the appropriate server application without further user action (ie., using the same browser window).

Now, poking around I've learned that I can obtain and display the hostname with the following script:

```
<script>
document.getElementById("hostname").innerHTML = 
"Hostname is: " + window.location.hostname + "<br/>"; 
</script>
```

Now what I want to do is something along the following (forgive any incorrect syntax):

```
<script>
if { hostname = "www.app1.com" {
  var url = "http://www.app1.com/isapi/app1/app1.dll/";
} else {
  if { hostname = "www.app2.com" {
    var url = "http://www.app1.com/isapi/app1/app2.dll/";
  } else {
    if { hostname = "www.app3.com" {
      var url = "http://www.app3.com/isapi/app1/app3.dll/";
    } else {
    }
  }
}
"GO TO URL";
</script>
```

How do I encode "GO TO URL" without buttons, etc., and further user action? I believe I need  a GET command, something like this:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', url, false);
xhr.send();
return;
```

but I can get this to execute.

Any suggestions most welcome.

Comment: Sorry, this line
        var url = "http://www.app1.com/isapi/app1/app2.dll/";
should be
    var url = "http://www.app2.com/isapi/app2/app2.dll/";

Answer (score 1):

Do you just want to redirect the user to a certain url?

You can do that through the location api.

```
window.location = "http://stackoverflow.com"
```

This will redirect the user to stackoverflow.com

So in your case just do: `window.location = url`

And since the the window object is the global scope you can just do `location = url`

**EDIT:**

And I would also recommend you using a switch statement instead of the nested if statements. It will be alot more readable:

```
var url = "";
switch(hostname){
  case "www.app1.com": 
    url = "url..."; break;
  case "otherdomain": 
    url = "url..."; break;
  default: 
    url = "url..."; //if none of the above ones
}
window.location = url;
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.Appreciate the "case" logic and the solution to load a new page. After some searching I also found the method as window.location.assign(url); I have it working.